# Android Expandable ListView - how to smooth scroll to a child position inside a group?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable listview. one of my groups, Group1, has 15 children. how can I smooth scroll to the 10th child upon clicking and expanding Group1?

Thanks.

Comment: check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74473330/5714364

Answer (score 4):

Override your adapter's `onGroupExpanded` method and call one the `smoothScrollToPosition` methods of your `ExpandableListView`. Something like:

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    // If it's the first group
    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        int scrollTo = groupPosition + 15;
        mExpList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(scrollTo, 0);
    }
}
```

Now remember that if there are other groups expanded before `groupPosition` the `scrollTo` will have to take that into account. So you might want to save all the *expanded group positions* (and their children counts) into an array and loop them every time `onGroupExpanded` and `onGroupCollapsed` is called.

That **might** look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    groupStates.put(groupPosition, 1);
    childrenCount.put(groupPosition, getChildrenCount(groupPosition));
    // Loop the group states
    int scrollTo = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<groupStates.size(); i++) {
        int position = groupStates.keyAt(i);
        // Cancel the loop if reached a further expanded group
        if (position > groupPosition) break;

        // 1 is the group to be skipped + its children count
        scrollTo += 1 + childrenCount.get(position);
    }
    // You can select specific child of the recently expanded group, to scroll to
    int childToScrollTo = 15; // make sure is an existing child
    // -1 because positions begin at index 1
    scrollTo = scrollTo - 1 + childToScrollTo;
    mExpList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(scrollTo, 0);
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    groupStates.remove(groupPosition);
    childrenCount.remove(groupPosition);
}
```

This is however untested so please do make sure you test it properly.